# How would one efficiently implement a nested structure containing arrays of other nested structures in a language that doesn't support them?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, nested

### Structure

This is the main structure I need to build, creating a type `tParent` (pseudocode, where `()` is an array declaration):

```
type Ne {
    single D()
    dword DC
    single B
    single V
    single D
}

type L {
    Ne Ns()
    dword NC
}

type tParent {
    L La()
    dword LC
    single LR
}

tParent nTest 

// would be accessed like nTest.La(0).Ns(0).B = 42 ...
```

However, the proprietary language that has to be used for this does not feature "arrays of user defined types". Nesting is supported, so apart from the `()` array declarations in the types above, the code is valid.

### Question

What is the most efficient way - algorithmically speaking - to implement this structure. I thought about expanding the subtypes into arrays, and accessing them using a second array that holds offsets, but I doubt this would be efficient in any way.

Comment: @JuanLopes For the record, it is this language: (https://github.com/minxomat/Perseus-6), however this question applies to many languages. I a looking for a more abstract answer, not an actual implementation. Hence the above "algorithmically speaking".

Comment: Yes, but it is hard to answer that without knowing what the language actually supports (does it support pointers? pointer arithmetic?)

Comment: @JuanLopes Pointers are not supported.

Comment: @minxomat - the documentation you linked to actually says pointers are supported with the @ operator, and treated as a dword.

Answer (score 1):

All I can suggest is create array of byte and work with it like you work with memory in assembly languages. You can hide complexity of memory access behind accessor methods like

```
 single typeName_fieldName_get(byte arr(), int offset) {
      return convertFomByteToSingle(
          arr(offset+OFFSET_OF_FIELD_NAME + 0),
          arr(offset+OFFSET_OF_FIELD_NAME + 1),
          arr(offset+OFFSET_OF_FIELD_NAME + 2),
          ....
          );
 }
```

Comment: That is kinda what I was mentioning in the OP. Because the actual number of members (and sub members) won't change after initialization, I'd create a function that monitors changes and accepts a string like "nTest.La(0).Ns(0).B = 42", searches the offset in the main array and returns the value. All values would be put into one big array of `single` values.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it should be possible to write an function that looks like

```
function("nTest", ["La","Ns"], ["0","0"]).b = 42
```

It acts much like a nested dictionary, in that the first element in the dictionary. The second element is the list of subdictionaries, and the 3rd element is the list of keys for the sub dictionaries. An alternative form that groups subdictionaries and their keys could be:

```
function("nTest", [["La","0"],["Ns","0"]]).b = 42
```

Although, the need to avoid using multiple types in an array would like require using something like below, but it may be tricky to handle if the nested structure does not have a predefined height:

```
function("nTest","La","0","Ns","0").b = 42
```

As for the contents of the function. It would basically just do this (but via a loop or recursion):

```
temp = nTest
temp = temp.La
temp = temp(0)
temp = temp.Ns
temp = temp(0)
return temp
```

This is close to how the functionality would be added to the language if I'm not mistaken after parsing. Though there may be a need to convert everything into string before putting into the function, then convert it back afterwords.

Although, since it's strictly typed, youll probably have to include the types, resulting in something like this:

```
function(["tParent","nTest"],["L","La"],["int","0"],["Ne","Ns"],["int","0"],["single","D"]) = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of since you can't use pointers is to use a linked list. Moving forward during iteration will be *O(1)* but lookups will of course be *O(n)* so depending on your use case it may not be the most efficient solution but it seems to me that it's the only one available without being able to store memory addresses in a primitive array to use as pointers.

```
type tParent {
    ListL La
    dword LC
    single LR
}

type ListL {
    NodeL First
}

type NodeL {
    NodeL Next
    L Value
}
```